# ngbPopover not showing up

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, ng-bootstrap

I'm trying to use the popover from ng-bootstrap (https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/popover) in my Angular2/Typescript app.

I don't even know how to state the question as there are no errors and yet, the popover is not showing.

this is the code that I have:

```
 <div ngbPopover="You see, I show up on hover!" 
      placement="top" triggers="mouseenter:mouseleave" title="Pop title"></div>
```

And this is my app config:

```
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        DependenciesComponent,
        TraceChartComponent
    ],
    imports: [
       NgbModule, 
    ...
```

Which is pretty much taken from their example site.

I'm fairly sure I've got all the required javascripts included as the `ngbTooltip` do work.

Is there anything else I need to do that I am missing here?

Comment: It is super-hard to see what is going on without seeing more code. I've prepared a minimal, working plunk, you might want to compare code in the plunk with yours: https://plnkr.co/edit/BoTsvDAhIETBkU64JvLk?p=preview

One thought - are you sure you are using Bootstrap 4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was resolved in the latest version ng-bootstrap (1.0.0-alpha.18).

running

> npm update @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap

should solve your issue.

https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/commit/60fd5d954cff7aa982dd328845689c039251ffe2

Answer (score 3):

If you are not using **Bootstrap 4 or 3**, you can simply override the default css of the `ngb-popover-window` tag and set the **css** `display` property to `block !important` in the file `style.css` like this:

```
   ngb-popover-window {
       position: absolute;
       width: auto !important;
       display: block !important;
       background-color: #fafafa !important;
       border: 1px solid #fafafa !important;
       max-width: none !important;
   }
```

And it should work.

Answer (score 0):

In the chrome dev console look at the element which is rendering ngb-popup, click on it and see the relevant css for that. You will be able to see the popup once you un-check the display:none style in .popup. 
Hence, its a css issue

PS. remove  triggers="mouseenter:mouseleave" so that default trigger is set to muse click so that you are able to inspect element properly

Comment: I've the same behaviour. The popover is appearing in the DOM with display:none style. I don't understand why so? How can I fix it, except style overwriting?